# Filter Firebase database with Multiple Conditions PHP

Tags: php, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

#### From last few days, I'm unable to find the solution of this Condition of using **AND** parameter in the Query

```
Example SQL QUERY `"SELECT * FROM `NotesMe` WHERE `Uid`='randomUid' AND Pin='Yep'"`
```

So I was unable to filter my database in firebase with Multiple Conditions Eg. WHERE AND

[**I'm working with the Firbase PHP SDK v6**](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

**I tried to filter the data with the as per the firebase filter documentation but i was only able to filter with a single condition**

```
$data = $database->getReference($ref)->orderByChild('Uid')->equalTo($uid)->getValue();
```

Above data Varible only returns the value in order to **UID** only

[image]

#### So I want filter that vaules with multiple Condition like `Where` UID `AND` PIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### So After searching a lot, I thought that should i make my own filter for this,

**so what as I know that the below `$data` variable is returns an filtered array with single condition of `OrderByChild`**

```
$data = $database->getReference($ref)->orderByChild('Uid')->equalTo($uid)->getValue();
```

So I decided ti filter that array again with a `PHP` array filter

```
$array = $data; // $data contains is already filtered array 
$filter_name ='Pin'; // another conditions
$filter_value ='yep';
$expected = array_filter($array, function($el) use ($filter_value, $filter_name) {
    return ($el[$filter_name] >= $filter_value);

});
```

**and finally it works now I'm able to use multiple conditions in firebase databse too with PHP**

**`$expected` contains the new re-filtered array**